# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream in data seeding using csv file

Tags: asp.net-core, database-migration, seeding

I am creating a Database seeding using CSV file in asp.net core and sql server.This is a multi driven data structure. for some entity following code update the data correctly .when i create a new csv file and try with a new entity it give me the value not found error.
Blow i give  my code example:

```
            Assembly Asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] names = Asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
            foreach (var name in names) Debug.WriteLine(name);
            string assemblyName = Asm.GetName().Name;
            string emailTemplateName = "IndustryAPI.Setup.VendorRating.csv";

            emailTemplateName = assemblyName + "." + emailTemplateName;

            string resourceName5 = "IndustryAPI.Setup.VendorRating.csv";
            using (Stream stream = Asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName5))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {

                    CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
                    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<VendorRatingMap>();
                    csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;

                    var Rat = csvReader.GetRecords<VendorRating>().ToArray();


                    foreach (VendorRating record in Rat)
                    {
                        customerList.Add(record);

                    }
                }
            }
            builder.Entity<VendorRating>().HasData(customerList);

 public class VendorRatingMap : ClassMap<VendorRating>
        {
            public VendorRatingMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.Id).Name("Id");
                Map(m => m.VendorId).Name("VendorId");
                Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");
                Map(m => m.Comment).Name("Comment");
                Map(m => m.Value).Name("Value");

            }
        }
```

[image: resource sample]
it reading only three resource file. I delete the csv file and create it again but still same problem. what did i wrong ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `Build Action` for `VendorRating.csv` is `Embedded resource`.

Right-Click `VendorRating.csv`->Build Action->Embedded resource.